# How to download files from S3 to a custom folder or a network path using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Below is the function to download the files from a S3 Bucket.
But the problem is I can't find how to direct those files into a network path instead of downloading into the project folder without having any control over where the files must be downloaded.

```
import boto3
import config
import os
import win32api

def download_all_objects_in_folder():
 #= boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=config.AWS_BUCKET_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=config.AWS_BUCKET_SECRET_KEY) 
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(config.BUCKET)
# Create the folder logic here
objects = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='Export_20181104/')
for obj in objects:
    path, filename = os.path.split(obj.key)
    my_bucket.download_file(obj.key, filename,"C:\Other")
    #win32api.MessageBox(0, obj.key, 'title')

print("imports completed")
```

Update:
This is the error I am getting when I pass the custom path.

```
ValueError: Invalid extra_args key 'C', must be one of: ChecksumMode, 
VersionId, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, 
RequestPayer, ExpectedBucketOwner
```

Comment: the path of the shared folder should be added the same way as the local path. Windows will recognize the path if your user have the access to it.

Comment: @GabrielDantas Thanks for the reply, I want to know where is that option to pass the location in the above code? (local or shared). If you have tried before, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference for Python or the Boto3 SDK where you download your specified S3 object, whether that is a local or network location.

That concern is up to the operating system.

Download to the network location, just as you would download to the local location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to know where is that option to pass the location in the above code? (local or shared). If you have tried before, please let me know.

Comment: Replace `shared path or local path here` with your path?

Comment: I have replaced please find the updated question (refresh the page). It is throwing some error.